# Average function in Python

Tags: python, jython, average

Write a program to continuously ask the user to enter numbers until the user enters a number that is greater than 100.  Then print the average value of the numbers before the last input. For instance, if the user enters 12, 23, 9, 15, 155, then the input terminates (because 155>100) and your program prints the average value of 12, 23, 9, 15, which is 14.75.

This is what I have so far and can't seem to get it to work correctly

```
def average():
 inputnum = 0
 numlist = []
while inputnum <=100:
 inputnum = input("Please input a number: ")
 inputnum = float(inputnum)
 numlist.append(inputnum)
average = sum(numlist)/len(numlist)
print(average)
```

Comment: what does not working correctly look like?  what error?  wha output?

Comment: there is definately some indentation errors in the code above ... not sure if thats real or just because you got stack overflow formatting wrong...

Comment: There is no errors reported. It just that the code includes the last number when it shouldn't. I can't seem to fix this

Comment: >>> average()
Please input a number: 50
Please input a number: 50
Please input a number: 101
67.0                        when the average should be 50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program works fine for me, but the indentation is wrong. It has to be like this:

```
def average():
    inputnum = 0
    numlist = []
    while inputnum <=100:
        inputnum = input("Please input a number: ")
        inputnum = float(inputnum)
        numlist.append(inputnum)
    average = sum(numlist)/len(numlist)
    print(average)

average() # finally call the function
```

To exclude the number entered that is greater than 100, do this:

```
def average():
    inputnum = 0
    numlist = []
    while inputnum <=100:
        inputnum = input("Please input a number: ")
        inputnum = float(inputnum)
        numlist.append(inputnum) if inputnum <=100 else None
    average = sum(numlist)/len(numlist)
    print(average)

average() # finally call the function
```

For Jython:

```
def average():
    inputnum = 0
    numlist = []
    while inputnum <=100:
        inputnum = input("Please input a number: ")
        inputnum = float(inputnum)
        if inputnum <= 100:
            numlist.append(inputnum)
    average = sum(numlist)/len(numlist)
    print(average)

average() # finally call the function
```

Comment: The problem that I have is that it is including the number that is greater than 100 when I enter. For example if I enter 75, 75 , 101 it returns 83.666666667 when the average should be 75. Any suggestions?

Comment: For a fraction of a minute, I had `numlist.pop()` in there. That didn't belong there.

Comment: I also edited the question if that helps any. I still am not sure why it is including the last value.

Comment: @Tobias: you got to it before I did.  I'll delete my answer.

Comment: >>> average()
Please input a number: 50
Please input a number: 50
Please input a number: 101
67.0 when the average should be 50

Comment: Are you sure you used my second example? I get: 50,50,101 --> 50.

Comment: If you are using a certain environment, you might have to reload the script.

Comment: I am now getting a error message on line 7. I am using jython for the environment

Comment: Well from the source code above I get Invalid syntax
Your code contains at least one syntax error, meaning it is not legal jython.
The error is on line 7

Comment: Ok, I do not know the Jython syntax specifica, but the third version could work if the short if-clause syntax is the problem.

Comment: Awesome thanks so I was forgetting the IF statement. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please don't forget to accept answers when your problem is solved. I am not fishing for compliments; if you did not do it, this question would remain flagged as open, which is not true. By accepting it, you mark it as solved :-)